# how to load fb:request-form in iframe / connect app using ajax

Tags: facebook, fbml, xfbml, facebook-iframe

how to load **fb:request-form** in iframe / connect facebook app using ajax calls?

for example [social city](http://apps.facebook.com/socialcity/) does it.

the POSTing of selected friend is also done in ajax. how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `target="_self"` attribute to `fb:request-form` tag, this way the form will be submitted to iframe rendered by Facebook without loading the response to the whole page.